# Is the language of TMs that halt on some string recognizable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I would like to show that the following language is recognizable:
$$L:= \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is a TM that halts on some string}\}.$$

How do I go about showing that this language is recognizable? I know that all recognizable languages are reducible to $HALT_\epsilon$, so I figure if I can show that this language reduces to $HALT_\epsilon$, then I am all set. I am defining $HALT_\epsilon$ as follows:

$$HALT_\epsilon:= \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is a TM that halts on } \epsilon \},$$

where $\epsilon$ is the empty string. We can reduce $HALT$ on $x$ to $HALT_\epsilon$ by a reduction $F(\langle M, x\rangle) = \langle M' \rangle $, where $M'(y) = M(x)$. For this reduction, we just ignore the input string $y$, which we know will be $\epsilon$ and just run $M$ on $x$ instead. Here, $HALT$ is defined as

$$HALT:= \{ \langle M,x \rangle \mid M \text{ is a TM that halts on } x \}.$$

I tried leveraging a similar technique to show that $L$ is recognizable, but I could not come up with anything better than this (somewhat crazy) TM that has a $HALT_\epsilon$ oracle:

$ D^{HALT_\epsilon} =$ On input $\langle M \rangle:$

1. Construct $N = $ "On input $x:$

   1. Run $M$ in parallel on all inputs $y\in \Sigma^*$.
   2. If $M$ halts on any $y$ then *accept*, otherwise *loop.*"
2. Query the oracle to determine whether $\langle N \rangle \in HALT_\epsilon$.
3. If the oracle answers YES, *accept*; if NO, *reject*.

*Note: My notation for TM algorithms is based on "Theory of Computation" by Sipser.* Step 2 for the definition of $N$ is a bit redundant, but in this type of context, is it okay to say something like "If $M$ halts on any $y$, then halt?"

I think all I have shown here is that $L$ is decidable relative to $HALT_\epsilon$. I don't know if this implies that $L$ is recognizable. Can a Turing reduction be used in this manner to show that a language is recognizable? I'm confused as to what it means for a language to be recognizable. The task seems obvious if we go back to the definition: If some TM $R$ accepts strings in $L$, then $R$ recognizes $L$. So what if $R=D^{HALT_\epsilon}$, and in the body of $D^{HALT_\epsilon}$ we use some crazy reduction like $N$?

In general, to show recognizability, can we just come up with a reduction like $N$ that may or may not halt? Is it a problem that $N$ will never halt if $\langle M \rangle \notin L$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can construct a recognizer following the same principle used for the recognizer for HALT. The only extra bit is how you check "all" inputs without getting stuck in a non-terminating computation.

An important technique you can use here is called [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_%28computer_science%29) (expressed with inputs from $\mathbb{N}$):

1. Simulate one step of $M$ on $1$.
2. Simulate two steps of $M$ on $1$ and $2$ each.
3. Simulate three steps on $1$, $2$ and $3$ each.

$\quad\vdots$

- Terminate and accept once any of the simulated computations terminates and accepts.

If there is a halting input of $M$, this dovetailed simulation certainly finds it after finite time. If there is none, it loops and is correct in doing so.

This is, in essence, your $N$ (with an explanation why it's actually a computable function). You don't need the rest of the reduction in order to show that $L$ is semi-decidable.

Comment: I added some clarification to my question, because I don't think I give a recognizer for $HALT$. What are you referring to when you say "the recognizer for $HALT$?"

So, $N$ is enough to show that $L$ is semi-decidable. Does semi-decidable imply recognizable? I think it does, because $N$ is a TM that recognizes strings in $L$. I just want to double check.

Comment: @baffld: Afaik, recognisable and semi-decidable mean the same thing; I just prefer the latter notion. To be safe, check the definitions you have in hand and compare to the TM I describe. (I was assuming you know a recognizer for HALT; if not, you should be able to come up with one after reading my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Use nondeterminism. Given $M$, guess a string $w \in \mathcal{L}(M)$, simulate $M$ on $w$ (use your trusty universal Turing machine as a subroutine) and accept if $M$ accepts $w$.

Comment: An example of the power of nondeterminism: It reduces many messy proofs into almost nothing.