# Is the language of all TMs *not* accepting a given string, Enumerable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, semi-decidability

Is the following language in **RE**?
$$L = \{\langle M\rangle : M\text{ is a TM that does not accept }010\}$$

I could use Rice's Theorem with the property $P = \{L : 010\text{ is not in }L\}$ to show it isn't in **R**, but how do I show it is in **RE**?

Comment: Hint, is $L$ in **co-RE**?

Comment: yes, I think it is :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic technique of dovetailing can be used to show the complement of $L$, $\{\langle M\rangle : M\text{ is a TM that accept }010\}$ is recursively enumerable. Check [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22929/is-the-language-of-tms-that-halt-on-some-string-recognizable?) for details.

Since $L$ is not decidable as shown by Rice's theorem, $L$ cannot be recursively enumerable.

---

**Exercise.** Show that $\{\langle M\rangle : M\text{ is a TM that accept } 010\text{ and }101\}$ is not in **RE**.