# Is the language L = {<M> | There exists an M' that stops on the same input words, but L(M) ≠ L(M')} in RE or R?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

Is the language $$L = \{M | \exists M' \text{ that stops on the same input words but L(M)} \neq L(M')\}$$ in RE or R?

I suspect that it's not in RE, since you'd have to first know for M all the inputs for which it halts, which you can't do in a finite time.

I wanted to show that $\overline {HP} \leq L$, and so because $\overline {HP} \notin RE$, also $L \notin RE$, but I can't seem to find a reduction function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice, that all machines $M$ that don't halt on any input accept the same language, $\emptyset$.
Thus if $M$ doesn't halt on any input then also $\langle M \rangle \notin L$.

Now define the TM $M'$ for some TM $M$ such that on input $x$

- $M'$ runs $M$ on $x$
- $M'$ rejects if $M$ halts accepting
- $M'$ accepts if $M$ halts rejecting

It's easy to see, that
$$M \text{ halts on } w \iff M' \text{ halts on } w$$
and that $L(M) \neq L(M')$ for all machines $M$ that halt on some input.
From this it follows that, if $M$ halts on some input, then $\langle M \rangle \in L$.

With this we have shown that
$$L = \{\langle M \rangle : M \text{ halts on some input}\}.$$
This language is [known to be in $\texttt{RE} \setminus \texttt{R}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22929/is-the-language-of-tms-that-halt-on-some-string-recognizable).

Comment: Why do all machines that halt on no input accept the empty set? Why can't a TM accept on the empty word?

Comment: @sadcat_1 There's no universal definition for TMs, but in general we define acceptance in a TM such that a machine $M$ accepts iff $M$ halts in an accepting state.

So if $w \in L(M)$ then $M$ must have stopped on $w$.
Therefore if $M$ doesn't halt on any $w$ then it can't have accepted anything, so $L(M) = \emptyset$.

Comment: My bad, I read "halt on no input" as "halt on empty word $\varepsilon$". Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I also read "halt on no input" as "halt on empty word". Maybe "doesn't halt on any input" would be less prone to this interpretation.

Comment: @Stef & sadcat_1 Thanks for the feedback!
Yeah, I can see how my phrasing was ambiguous, I'll fix it right away.